# Phonegap app suddenly quit after downloading the app from AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

My app is live on the AppStore. I have used cordova 2.5. Past few days people give me the feedback that the app quit unexpectedly after downloading from the AppStore. The users with whom this problem occurred, mostly have iPhone 5 and iPod touch with iOS 7. I have download the app from the AppStore on iPhone5 on which iOS 7 is installed but it is working fine. I have already given the press release to 100 media channels and it is very crucial problem for me at this time. Please someone help me. I shall be thankful to you.

Comment: On the other hand, AFAIK cordova less than 3.1 was not oficially ready for XCode 5 and iOS 7. It will be better to update the project to be covered also on that side.